# Half-open topology on $\mathbb R$ is separable, and $A \setminus \hat A$ is countable

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

This is part of Exercise 9 in Section 2.2 of *Topology and Groupoids*, by Brown.

For each $x \in \mathbb R, N \subseteq \mathbb R$ is a neighborhood of $x$ if and only if there are real numbers $x^{\prime}, x^{\prime \prime}$ such that $x \in [ x^{\prime}, x^{\prime \prime}) \subseteq N$. This is called the half-open topology on $\mathbb R$.

I am supposed to show that this topological space is separable, and that if $\hat A$ is the set of limit points of a set $A \subseteq \mathbb R$, then $A \setminus \hat A$ is countable.

**My attempt:**

The space is separable because the subset $\mathbb Q \subseteq \mathbb R$ is countable, and every neighborhood of every point must intersect $\mathbb Q$.

Showing that $A \setminus \hat A$ is countable seems harder. I thought about proving it by contradiction. Assume it were uncountable. So there are uncountably many $x \in A$ that have at least one neighborhood that contains no other points of $A$. So there are uncountably many intervals $[a, b)$ that contain only one point of $A$.

I was going to say that none of the intervals can intersect, but I'm not sure that's true.

I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

If there are uncountably many such points, does that mean they have to form at least a finite interval? Then there couldn't be uncountably many intervals $[a, b)$ each only containing one of the points within a finite interval, right?

Comment: You can save typing by using  apostrophes, i.e. x' and x'' inside dollars gives $x'$ and $x''$. The topology is also called the Sorgenfrey Line, or the lower-limit topology.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet Thank you for the tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right about the countable dense subset. (every set $[a,b)$ contains an open interval $(a,b)$ which contains a rational etc.)

If $a \in A\setminus \hat{A}$, then there is a basic subset $[a,f(a))$ with $f(a) \in \Bbb Q$ such that $[a,f(a)) \cap A = \{a\}$ (this is what not being a limit point entails, plus we use the density of $\Bbb Q$). Suppose that we have $a_1 < a_2$ in $ A\setminus \hat{A}$ and $f(a_1) = f(a_2)$. But then $a_2 \in [a_1, f(a_1)$ and this contradicts how $f(a_1)$ was chosen. So $f: A\setminus \hat{A} \to \Bbb Q$ is injective and so  the domain of $f$  is at most countable.

Comment: Thanks for your help. The conclusion that the former set is at most countable---is that like a corollary of Theorem 4 from here: http://www.math.toronto.edu/ivan/mat327/docs/reqs.pdf? It's a type of pigeonhole principle, right?

Comment: @Novice no, theorem 2,  under countability. If we have an injection into a countable set (there $\Bbb N$, but $\Bbb Q$ has the same size so also works) the domain is countable. $ 2 \to 1$ from this equivalence.

Comment: Is the Sorgenfrey Line hereditarily separable?

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yes, any monotonically normal separable space is.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the term "monotonically normal".

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the Sorgenfrey line is a GO space, which is a subclass of monotonically normal spaces. Of course besides quoting a general result, it’s easy enough to prove directly too.